# Clone and resize a div relatively to its contents

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, html, resize

First of all I'd like to say - I don't want someone to do my coding. I'm just looking for tips/pointers/suggestion.

**Background:**

*I'm using jQuery and jQueryUI drag/drop*

1. I have a droppable div with dimensions 500px x 500px. This is `#div-droppable`.
2. I have a draggable div with same dimensions as `#div-droppable`. Let us call it `#div-draggable`.
3. There are a lot of draggable products from `#div-draggable` that are possible to drag to `#div-droppable`.
4. Each product in `#div-draggable` has dimension 50px x 50px.

***Example:***
I have dragged 50 products from `#div-draggable` to `#div-droppable`, and they are now absolutely positioned within the `#div-droppable`.

Now I want to save the content in `#div-droppable` to a third DIV called `#div-draft`. The `#div-draft` has the dimension 250px * 250px. I want the products located in `#div-droppable` being stored related to the `#div-draft`.

**My thoughts:**

If one dragged product is absolutely positioned within the `#div-droppable` with left: 50px and top:100px, the same product in `#div-draft` would be positioned with left:25px and top:50px (because `#div-draft` is half the size of `#div-droppable`). Also the size of each product would be half the size (25px * 25px)

I could do some calculation (as described above) of all products in `#div-droppable` and put each product in `#div-draft`

**My question:**
Is there any other way/smarter way/better way of doing this? I'm basically looking to clone a certain divs (`#div-droppable`) content into another div (`#div-draft`) but I want the content to be resized relatively to the size of `#div-draft`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you would do this, of course, depends on the content, but I'm assuming your not using an image. If you were this would be simple, just use CSS to change the size of your image. You can't clone a group of contents, unless you make a function that uses jQuery's `.css()` method. You will have to recalculate everything in your CSS, or jQuery.

See:
http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: Ok, I guess this answered my question. Thank you! :-)